# ASP.NET xml linq check if element exist

Tags: xml, linq, conditional-statements

xml structure example:

```
<item>
   <title>Foo</title>
   <description>Boo</description>
   <image>Poo</image>
</item>
```

and my code is:

```
var rssFeeds =
              from feed in rssXML.Descendants("item")             
              select new
              {                  
                  Title = feed.Element("title").Value,                  
                  Description = feed.Element("description").Value,                                                                                                 
                  Image= feed.Element("image").Value, 
              };
```

the question is how can I check if the "title" element exist in the code above...if not exists take some other element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the explicit `XElement` to string conversion (which converts a null `XElement` reference to a null string reference) in conjunction with the null coalescing operator:

```
Title = (string) feed.Element("title") ?? (string) feed.Element("otherElement")
```